# Re-enabling a button after closing a popup window

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a button on a form page that opens a popup in which a user can calculate the prices of various options before submitting the form.

However, I want the button that opens the popup to be disabled while the window is open, and enabled while it's closed.

Disabling the button is easy: `calculatorButton.disabled = true;` works just fine inside the click event.

What I can't work out is how to enable the button again when the popup is closed.

`newWindow.onunload` hasn't worked, nor has `newWindow.onbeforeunload`.

Comment: Do you use a plugin for your popup or what?

Comment: as a slight workaround, you can use js in-page popups (which are also far less annoying). then attaching this event is easy

Comment: I'm not using a plugin, ebram. I'm just mucking around with javascript for a school assignment, trying to learn stuff. 

What do you mean by 'js in-page popup', amdixon?

Right now, I'm using:

`var newWindow = window.open()`

Comment: something like [simplemodal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal-demos/). it doesnt open a whole new window and will be easier and more standard to interface with through js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set a timer to check whether the child window has been closed :

```
var child = window.open();
var id = setInterval(function () {
    if (child.closed) {
        clearInterval(id);
        calculatorButton.disabled = false;
    }
}, 100); // check every 100ms
```

That said, I would not disable the button and rather check `closed` like so :

```
var child = window.open();
calculatorButton.onclick = function () {
    if (!child.closed) return;
    // else do something
};
```

I've never used `closed` by the way : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_closed.asp.

Comment: Thanks, that's actually a pretty good idea, although I've just now realised that I don't actually *need* the button disabled; I just need it to not do what it usually does if the user decides to click it while the calculator is already open. 

Anyhow, thanks. :)